# creating new rows based on values in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have a data frame with 717 unique rows, what I want to do now is, assuming the reference and joining MeSH ID are different, create new rows below where I move the reference ID into the same column as the Joining MeSH ID, deleting the reference MeSH ID column as I do so but keeping all other data in the row the same. So if a row in the table currently looks something like this:

| Disease | Joining Mesh ID | Company | Mode of Action | Reference MeSH ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acute Myeloid Leukemia | D015470 | Gilead | CD3 agonist | D007951 |

I want the final product to look something like this:

| Disease | Mesh ID | Company | Mode of Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acute Myeloid Leukemia | D015470 | Gilead | CD3 agonist |  |
| Acute Myeloid Leukemia | D007951 | Gilead | CD3 agonist |

(There are 25 columns  in total, but I've only shown a few for the sake of simplicity.)

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this is what im doing now coincidentally looking for AML drugs Im curious why you have two different MESH ID for same AML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Disease    Joining_Mesh_ID Company Mode_of_Action  Reference_MeSH_ID
'Acute Myeloid Leukemia'    D015470 Gilead  'CD3 agonist'   D007951")

library(tidyverse)
df %>% pivot_longer(ends_with('_ID'), names_to = NULL, values_to = 'Mesh_ID')

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   Disease                Company Mode_of_Action Mesh_ID
#>   <chr>                  <chr>   <chr>          <chr>  
#> 1 Acute Myeloid Leukemia Gilead  CD3 agonist    D015470
#> 2 Acute Myeloid Leukemia Gilead  CD3 agonist    D007951
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
library(tidverse)
dat %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(Disease, Company, Mode.of.Action), values_to="Mesh ID", names_to = NULL)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Disease                Company Mode.of.Action `Mesh ID`
  <chr>                  <chr>   <chr>          <chr>    
1 Acute Myeloid Leukemia Gilead  CD3 agonist    D015470  
2 Acute Myeloid Leukemia Gilead  CD3 agonist    D007951
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

DF %>%
  rename_with(~ str_to_title(.x), contains("ID")) %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(Disease, Company, `Mode of Action`), names_to = c(NA, ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(\\w+)\\s(.*)")

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Disease                Company `Mode of Action` `Mesh Id`
  <chr>                  <chr>   <chr>            <chr>    
1 Acute Myeloid Leukemia Gilead  CD3 agonist      D015470  
2 Acute Myeloid Leukemia Gilead  CD3 agonist      D007951
```